# How to properly define optional parameters in method

Tags: c#, .net, methods

I have a method like this:

```
public static bool PrintSomething(Product p, Customer c = null, int ordinalNumber)
{
 // ..My code 
}
```

Sometimes I would pass this `ordinalNumber`, and sometimes I wouldn't, so basically that means this should be optional parameter? Am I right?

So I'm wondering what is proper way to define it?
Assigning it to null or any value?

Any kind of help would be cool, thanks!

Comment: **[If only there was an online reference to basic questions like this...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments)**  or an easy way to find them

Comment: Depending on how you use your parameter in `// ..My code`, you can assign it to -1 and check if it is larger than -1 do one thing if not - other. Or make it nullable and check if it is null//

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since "properly" could have different meanings, I'll throw one more option out there:

```
public class PrintRequest
{
    public Product Product { get; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public int? OrdinalNumber { get; set; }

    public PrintRequest(Product product)
    {
         if(product = =null)
             throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(product));
         Product = product;
    }
}

public static bool PrintSomething(PrintRequest printRequest)
```

Now the method doesn't have three arguments, some of them optional: it has one. 
The definition of `PrintRequest` makes it possible to omit `Customer` and `OrdinalNumber`, but it's impossible to omit `Product`.

The mileage of this approach varies, but one of the intents is just to avoid creating an ever-growing list of optional arguments.

Comment: @RandyLevy in a way I'm kicking the can down the road. I'm showing a way to handle optional method parameters, but using this approach he still has to construct the object. Perhaps the biggest difference is that unlike a method call with a list of arguments, he doesn't have to provide them all at once. I wouldn't automatically convert three arguments into an object, but if it continues growing then it's good to understand the approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static bool PrintSomething(Product p, Customer c = null, int ordinalNumber = -1)
{
}
```

I presume the ordinalNumber is the index of an item in a list, so it can not be negative when it is filled in:

```
if (orindalNumber < 0) // parameter was not filled i
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use method overloading by declareing two methods with the same name but different signatures:

```
public static bool PrintSomething(Product p, Customer c = null)
{
 // ..My code 
}

public static bool PrintSomething(Product p, Customer c = null, int ordinalNumber)
{
 // ..My code 
}
```

Now when you call your method `PrintSomething` your `ordinalNumber` parameter is optional.

Comment: If you have ~20+ lines of code and the difference is in one of them only, then this is a bad practice to copy-paste, better add a default value that you will check in your method

Answer (score -1):

Optional parameters are defined at the end of the parameter list,

```
public static bool PrintSomething(Product p, int ordinalNumber, Customer c = null)
{
 // ..Your code 
}
```

ref https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments

Comment: If you red carefully my question you would see this "
Sometimes I would pass this ordinalNumber, and sometimes I wouldn't, so basically that means this should be optional parameter?" so I want to say, that I want to define ordinalNumber also as optional parameter and I'm wondering how to do that?

Comment: @billy_56 by specifying default value for it if not present?

Comment: @billy_56 correct, your question title leads me to give that answer, btw @ LisL answer will help you, thanks